# How can I call a child function in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need to call a child function from the parent but I don't know how,

This is parent component calling to child component

```
<QuestionC @childfunction></QuestionC>
```

This is a child component

```
methods: {
  childfunction: function () {
    alert('hello')
  }
},
```

Comment: You can access all child components by `this.$root.$children`, but I think it's better to using `ref` to get the target component that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it using its `ref` ... like this:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: ' ',
  methods: {
    childfunction: function() {
      alert('hello')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    callChild() {
      this.$refs.child.childfunction();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="child"></child>
  <button @click="callChild()">CallChild</button>
</div>
```